# How do you use the value in one field to pull a corresponding value in another field?

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I have a table that looks something like this:

[image: Table Image]

The field column is a catch-all for custom fields and is linked properly to other tables. What I need to do is to search through and exclude any Trans ID's that have a Trans Completed Field. So in this instance it would filter out A00001 and A00003.

I know I can use record select and remove those Trans ID's, but now my data shows each of the entries in the field column when really I'm just trying to exclude any Trans Id that has an entry for Trans Completed, and give me one entry for each Trans ID.

Is there a formula that I can use to filter the loan? I don't have access to edit the database directly to pull the data into a new table. I've tried subreports in crystal but it pulls multiple entries.

---Updated 10/12/15---

So in the end I want it to look something like this.

[image: End Result]

Comment: can you explain more on this ` I'm just trying to exclude any Trans Id that has an entry for Trans Completed, and give me one entry for each Trans ID. `

Answer (score 0):

you could 
create a formula if {field} ] "Trans Completed" then 1 else 0
create a group on TRANS ID
in GROUP Selection expert enter 
sum({field},{TRANS ID}) = 0